# Tuple Subtract statement in Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, tuples

using python I am wanting to subtract 256 from a value in the list if a value is greater than 256, but i want the output to be in a tuple format, this is where i need help.

```
x = [85, 229, 162, 45, 280, 186, 275, 265, 252, 188, 135, 150, 351, 326, 217, 43, 301, 281, 333, 39, 246, 150, 139, 186, 195, 132, 196, 171, 307, 272, 97, 330, 271, 179, 276, 141, 151, 214, 191, 111, 261, 290, 146]

for y in x:
    if y>256:
        print y-256
    else:
        print y
```

This code will give the correct output, but in a list format.

Comment: what would the tuple values contain ?

Comment: what do you mean? are you asking what i am using it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of printing the values, append them to a list:

```
z = []
for y in x:
    if y>256:
        z.append(y-256)
    else:
        z.append(y)
```

You can shorten the `if/else` statement like this:

```
z = []
for y in x:
    z.append(y-256 if y>256 else y)
```

And then, you can put all these lines into a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
z = [y-256 if y > 256 else y for y in x]
```

Answer (score 5):

To get list use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) / [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

```
>>> x = [85, 229, 162, 45, 280, 186, 275, 265, 252, 188, 135, 150, 351, 326, 217, 43, 301, 281, 333, 39, 246, 150, 139, 186, 195, 132, 196, 171, 307, 272, 97, 330, 271, 179, 276, 141, 151, 214, 191, 111, 261, 290, 146]
>>> [y - 256 if y > 256 else y for y in x]
[85, 229, 162, 45, 24, 186, 19, 9, 252, 188, 135, 150, 95, 70, 217, 43, 45, 25, 77, 39, 246, 150, 139, 186, 195, 132, 196, 171, 51, 16, 97, 74, 15, 179, 20, 141, 151, 214, 191, 111, 5, 34, 146]
>>> tuple(y - 256 if y > 256 else y for y in x)
(85, 229, 162, 45, 24, 186, 19, 9, 252, 188, 135, 150, 95, 70, 217, 43, 45, 25, 77, 39, 246, 150, 139, 186, 195, 132, 196, 171, 51, 16, 97, 74, 15, 179, 20, 141, 151, 214, 191, 111, 5, 34, 146)
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, you can use [map(function, iterable, ...)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function or generator expressions. Generators were explained earlier in this thread, so I'll show you example of `map`:

```
my_list = [85, 229, 162, 45, 280, 186, 275, 265, 252, 188, 135, 150, 351, 326, 217, 43, 301, 281, 333, 39, 246, 150, 139, 186, 195, 132, 196, 171, 307, 272, 97, 330, 271, 179, 276, 141, 151, 214, 191, 111, 261, 290, 146]
my_list = tuple(map(lambda x: (x - 256) if x > 256 else x, my_list))
```